# what is the meaning of |a−b|max(1,|b|)

Tags: sequences-and-series

i have seen this formula when i try to solve a problem in competitive programming. i am not able to get it what this formula is doing. Help me to understand this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: It takes the absolute value of $a-b$ and then finds which is the bigger number between $1$ and the absolute value of b and then multiplies these 2 values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You take the absolute value $|a-b|,$ and then multiply it by the maximum of $1$ and $|b|.$

Comment: Thanks Michael Barz. i am not able to understand absolute value |a-b| and multiply it by maximum of 1 and |b|. can  you please give me some example .

Comment: @Shimaan If $a=3$ and $b=7,$ then $|a-b| = 4.$ The maximum of $1$ and $|b|$ is $7,$ so we multiply $4\cdot 7 = 28.$ It might be more worthwhile for you to review high school algebra.

Comment: Thanks very much @Michael Barz